# Inaccessible base class despite friendship

Tags: c++, inheritance, friend

There are tons of questions regarding this error and all of the answers seem to imply that downcasting is impossible. Only [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44488594/10627427) mentions friendship as possible solution, at least as I understand it. However the following code (irrelevant stuff removed for clarity) does not compile:

```
class C;

class A {
    friend class C;  // this does not help
};

class B : protected A {
    friend class C;  // this does not help either
};

class C {
    public:
    void foo(A* a) {};
};

B b;
C c;

void bar()
{
    c.foo(&b);  // this produces error: class A is an inaccessible base of B
}
```

Why friendship does not work on a reference? After all, "C" is perfectly capable of calling protected methods of "A" through pointer to "B".

The full error is

```
prog.cc: In function 'void bar()':
prog.cc:20:13: error: 'A' is an inaccessible base of 'B'
   20 |     c.foo(&b);
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is that the conversion from `B*` to `A*` (the one which requires friendship) does not happen in a member function of `C`, but in the context of the code containing `b` and `c` (i.e. the unrelated function `bar()`).

It would work fine if you created a member function in `C` accepting a `B*`, and then called `foo()` from within it. That would have the conversion happen within the context of `C` which has the necessary access rights (thanks to friendship).

Comment: Oh, interesting! So, what you are saying, it is not enough for calling context to have an access to class C and class C be a friend of A. It is also necessary for a calling context to be a friend of A as well, right?

Comment: @Maple It's the caller of `foo` who does the conversion from `B*` to `A*`, which requires the protected access.

Comment: @Angew made sure the calling context is a friend of "A" and it works! thanks a lot for the explanation!

Answer (score 14):

Your code is equivalent to this:

```
B b;
C c;
A * a = &b; // <- This cast produces the error
c.foo(a);
```

You cannot cast `&b` as `A*` since the base class is protected, regardless of the friendship of `C`.

Answer (score 1):

In the global scope B is not visible as A, because of protected inheritance.

Only class B itself, classes inherited from B and class C (because the friendship relation) "know" that B is inheriting A. But the rest of the world (including global scope) doesnt'.

So to achieve what you want, you could call

```
c.foo(&b)
```

within C scope, for example using some wrapper function, something like (although bad design decision):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

class C;


class A {
    friend class C;  // this does not help
};

class B : protected A {
    friend class C;  // this does not help either
};

class C {
public:
    void foo() {
        B b;
        foo(&b);  // this call is OK within C-scope
    }
private:
    void foo(A* /*a*/) {
        std::cout << "C::foo(A* a)\n";
    };
};


int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello, Wandbox!" << std::endl;
    B b;
    C c;
    //c.foo(&b);  // this produces error: class A is an inaccessible base of B
    c.foo();      // this is calling c.foo(A*) internally
}
```

or [live](https://wandbox.org/permlink/F2qF9VYwbEGzYny6):

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 You are correct, the placement of a call turns out to be important and should have been included in the example. Ironically, this became obvious to me only _after_ I got an answer. I updated the code in the question.

Comment: @Maple nothing personal, but i dislike the term "obvious". nothing is really obvious ;) still `foo` is not accesible but at least your example now has the error you report. If you dont mind I'll add the error message to your quesiton

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 I returned that "public" back into code to avoid any confusion and focus on actual problem

Comment: @Maple yep. Note that changeing the code after you got an answer is actually not optimal either because it can break answers. Luckily this answer still applies with minial change (global scope -> bar scope). I know it isnt easy to create a good mvce, but leaving out stuff is confusing rather than simplifying most of the time

Comment: Hm – if we just consider accessibility, the answer is fine. Having a separate `B` instance is, globally seen, critical, though, as foo might modify it – but later in main, the unmodified `b` might be used. Possibly having two public foo overloads, one accepting `A*`, one accepting `B*` and the latter one just doing the cast as needed for calling the former might be less intervening...